# Ruby: reverse calculation or spreadsheet function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a module that calculates about 150-200 values. Once it's done, I want the ability to edit one or some of the results—which may or may not be one of the original, non-calculated values—and have the other results update, like the functionality of a spreadsheet.

The problem is I really don't know where to start. The module's code looks largely like this:

```
if @user.override > 0
  h[:floor] += (@user.override / h[:size]) * 0.03
end

if @user.other_override > 0
  h[:floor] += (@user.other_override / h[:size]) * 0.03
end
```

And is quite *chronological*, making this task even tougher.

Is there any approach here that'll work? I can barely wrap my head around how it might, other than to leverage an actual spreadsheet into my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "[Reactive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)". Many languages have an implementation of the [ReactiveX framework](https://github.com/ReactiveX), so does Ruby: [RxRuby](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxRuby)